# Modern equivalent of the Motorola 68000?(In power and price)

Tags: processor

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000

I've been designing a modern 16-bit console in my head for fun. Most 16-bit consoles of the time used the 68k, but I want one which is still being manufactured
(There may be clones of the 68k, but I don't want those).

Is there a modern 16-bit processor around the same speed and power of the 68k? I've had no luck digging through the slop that google brings up.